# Button error inside switch + if

Tags: android

I am facing an issue with Buttons: I created a switch with a onClickListener inside it and if/else inside the onClick Listener.
The problem is that if I try to modify button state (I want to change background color) inside the if statement I get an error.
If I write the same line outside the if/else brakets it does work. What am I missing?

EDIT: the resource is ok, it does work in other activities. The problem is that if I type risp1. Eclipse doesn't give me an hint box as usuale and shows me the error "risp1 cannot be resolved into a type".
The app doesn't crash, it works, but it doesn't change the background color of the botton as I want (I get a transparent black color).

```
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QScalata extends Activity{

SharedPreferences SPavanzamento;
int ndomanda=0,caso;
TextView domanda;
public Button risp1,risp2,risp3,risp4;
int intdomanda,scelta;
String Domanda1[],Domanda2[],Domanda3[];
String RispQ1[] = null;
String RispQ2[]= null;
String RispQ3[]= null;
String RispQ4[]= null;

int esatto1[]={1,1,1};
int esatto2[]={1,1,1};



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.qscalata);

    domanda = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDomandaS);
    risp1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1S);
    risp2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2S);
    risp3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3S);
    risp4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4S);

    Domanda1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.QScalata);
    RispQ1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.RispQ1);
    RispQ2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.RispQ2);
    RispQ3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.RispQ3);
    RispQ4 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.RispQ4);

    SPavanzamento = getSharedPreferences("avanzamento", 0);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    ndomanda = extras.getInt("extra");

    switch(ndomanda){
    case 1:
        Random random= new Random();
        caso=random.nextInt(3);
        domanda.setText(Domanda1[caso]);
        risp1.setText(RispQ1[caso]);
        risp2.setText(RispQ2[caso]);
        risp3.setText(RispQ3[caso]);
        risp4.setText(RispQ4[caso]);

        risp1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                scelta=1;
                if(scelta==esatto1[caso]){
                    risp1.setBackgroundColor(65280);
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                         public void run() { 
                             risp1.setBackgroundColor(R.color.transparent_bg);
                             SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SPavanzamento.edit();
                             editor.putInt("avanzamento", 1);
                             editor.commit();
                             Intent returnMenu = new Intent("metal.quiz.SCALATA");
                             startActivity(returnMenu);
                         } 
                    }, 1000);

                }else{
                    risp1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);    
                }
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                     public void run() { 
                         finish();
                     } 
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
        break;
```

Comment: If your app crashes, you should always post your LogCat errors in your question.

Comment: "The app doesn't crash it works, but it doesn't change the background color of the botton as I want." You should read iccthedral's answer, if you aren't getting the correct background color.

Comment: That's not the problem: if I type the name of the variable and a . (point) eclipse doesn't show the hint box, just as it doesn't understand it is a button. The variable cannot be resolved into a type. If I write it outside that if it does work as always. I don't understand why. Screenshot: http://postimage.org/image/awkby5f45/

Comment: So project compiles without an error, but eclipse is bugging you?

Comment: Yes, but the apps also behave strangely: I have 15 button like that (case 1,2,...15 in the switch) and the change of the background works only for 2 of them... the code is obviously the same (copy-paste changing only the value of the variables). I'm trying to re-write the code from scratch... it seems it works, but it's kinda strange

Comment: Update: code rewritten. No errors. Run the app: same behavior as above. And the same problem in the new code AFTER the first run of the app.

Comment: Have you read my answer?

Comment: Of course... I guess I can get rid of the error creating a different activity for each button, but I don't really like that way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

> "risp1 cannot be resolved into a type"

This simply means that your haven't declared `risp1` correctly. I assume the `risp1` is a Button, so you want to make a class variable like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    // You forgot "Button" or whatever type risp1 should be
    public Button risp1; 
    ...

    public void onCreate(...) {
```

---

**Addition**
I see, you *have* given `risp1` a type but you failed to import it with:

```
import android.widget.Button;
```

(You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to import your dependencies automatically.)

Comment: I did it... my buttons weren't set as public, but doing it doesn't change anything. The issue is ONLY inside the onClickListener.

Comment: Button is already imported: import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

Comment: Please post more of your code, especially where you declare `risp1`.

Comment: Since it is only that occurrence of `risp1` that is showing an error, have you tried deleting that line and Cleaning your project? (**Project** -> **Clean...**)